# Object and function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I am looking for a shorter way to make a JavaScript object that can be used as a function. For instance, I can do the following:

```
var A=function(){window.alert('Hello World');}
A.hello='World';
```

Notice that I can call `A()` or access `A.hello`.

Is there a way to accomplish this using curly braces to create the object?

```
var A={
    ?:function(){window.alert('Hello World');},
    hello:'World',
};
```

Comment: No, only functions can be used as functions (are callable). But as functions are objects as well you can easily assign properties to them.

Comment: If you just want shorter you can omit the `var` statement and say `function A() ...` with effectively the same result. But as per _am not i am_'s answer there isn't a syntax to create a function and give it properties all in one statement.

Comment: Whats its the point? I mean if you replace ? by $ you easy could do A.$() and get the result with only two extra characters, what do you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know a function is an Object. Nothing prevents you from writing properties in the function itself.

```
function A(){
    this.width = 200;
}

A.height = 120;
```

If you want to access the properties written in the function from the function itself, you must use the 'callee' attribute of the 'arguments':

```
function A(){
    this.width = 200;
    alert(this.width +'x'+ arguments.callee.height);
}

A.height = 120;

A(); // should alert "200x120"
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"Is there a way to accomplish this using curly braces to create the object?"*

No, there's no official syntax to create callable objects other than creating a `Function` object.

Answer (score 0):

by the first way, A is a function, you can use it like this: A();

by the second way, A is an object